# Creating and Querying a Volatile table using Teradata JDBC in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark, teradata

I am getting the following error when using Spark 1.5.1 when querying a Volatile Table in Teradata:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or '(' between the 'FROM' keyword and the 'CREATE' keyword.
```

This is the code I am running that generates the above error:

```
val url = "jdbc:teradata://FOO/, TMODE=TERA,TYPE=DEFAULT"
val properties = new java.util.Properties()
val driver = "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"
properties.setProperty("driver",driver)
properties.setProperty("username","USER")
properties.setProperty("password","PASSWORD")

var query =
f"""
  CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE tmp AS
      ( SELECT * FROM database.table )
      WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(CR_PLCY_ID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

  COMMIT;      

  SELECT * FROM tmp;
"""

var df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,query,properties)
```

Sidenote : I have oversimplified the original query to test the functionality of Volatile tables within a query over the JDBC. The original query has multiple volatile tables.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly what's going on, but you can't use a `FASTEXPORT` connection to create a Volatile Table. Btw, you request `SESSIONS=10` and a VT be *session-local*.

Comment: Thanks! I will change from FASTEXPORT to see if I can create the Volatile Tables.

Comment: I received the following error when I change "TYPE=FASTEXPORT" to "TYPE=DEFAULT" and remove the "SESSIONS=10"                                                                                Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or '(' between the 'FROM' keyword and the 'CREATE' keyword.

Comment: It's the same error message? I can't help you any further, as I don't know about Spark. It just seems to wrap your query into something else, looks like a `SELECT * FROM your_query`. If you have access to the QueryLog you might find the source actually submitted to Teradata in bc.QryLogV (or QryLogSQL). And there will be another problem: You submit both CREATE and SELECT as a single request, which is not allowed, the CREATE must be committed.

Comment: Unless you have oversimplified your code above, there isn't a need for the volatile table. Simply run the `SELECT * FROM {database}.{table};` for the FastExport that you are using to seed the volatile table.

Comment: @RobPaller Thanks for the response! Yes I have oversimplified my code quite a bit. My original query is pretty extensive in comparison(around 4-5 volatile tables being queried) and I wanted to start with a simple test case and extrapolate from there.

Comment: @dnoeth I added a "COMMIT;" between the CREATE and the SELECT commands and it still generates the exact same error as before.

Comment: You can't commit within a *Multi Statement Request* (= the SQL string submitted to the DB), you need to submit one CREATE after the other. And there's no `COMMIT` in a `TMODE=TERA` session, in fact transaction handling is quite quirky in JDBC: forums.teradata.com/forum/teradata-studio/v15-10-3-commit-processing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scala,  nor Spark,  but looking at the Java doc for the read.jdbc method ([Spark Javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#jdbc(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties))),  it is expecting a table name as the second parameter.

So, the Spark library is doing some sort of "select * from (table parameter value)" and this justifies the error message (as dnoeth had already said)